# How are assets distributed by types of organisations?

Tags: macroeconomics, money, firm, capital-structure, asset-prices

How wealth, assets or capital (measured in terms of revenues, assets, equity, etc.) is distributed among the various types of organizations (e.g. State, public companies, private conpanies, individuals) existing in an economy?

Comment: What is it that you are asking? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Are you asking how assets move between organisations (i.e. part of is the answer to your question "trade")? Or are you asking how much asset value each type of organisation owns: which seems odd, as it will vary by economy and over time.

Comment: I am asking the last question you mentioned. Why is it odd just because it varies? Are you meaning that it is a difficult question?

Comment: What I mean is - what sort of answer would be useful? If someone says: 70% is owned by the State, 10% by individuals, 20% by companies, then what problem does that help you solve? Even if they specified the country and year for which it was true, I can't see what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: A question on justice and equity about the distribution of wealth. Is it irrelevant? Or should I add this reason to the description of the question?

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound like an economics problem. Again, what is the economics problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: No specific economic problem. Just a question of interest. Should I then delete this question?

Answer (score 3):

The [Flow of Funds](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/current/) (Financial Accounts of the United States) should have what you need.

For example, table  [B.1 Net National Wealth Table Description Table](https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/DisplayTable.aspx?t=b.1) (Billions of dollars; amounts outstanding end of period, not seasonally adjusted) might be very close to what you want.

[image]